# how to solve get lock error

Tags: 14.04

[sudo] password for mohamed: 
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Comment: It mostly occurs when you are installing some packages and force quit in between, try logging out and then login again.

Answer (score 0):

1)run ps -aux command 
Find the process with apt as in their name and kill those processes using
kill -9 process-id

2) Remove that lock file using rm commnad..
-i recommended to do first method